# "Worry free life" - does this make sense?

Tags: grammar

> I want to live a worry free life.

Does this make sense? I use this phrase a lot, but I am not sure
if this is grammatically correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Would it be better to say "I want to live without worry"? What you say makes sense (I can understand it), but why repeat the 'life' concept? You've already said it with "live".

Comment: Nah, it's fine as is.  Quit worrying about it.

Comment: You might consider adding a hyphen to _worry-free_ to make it more obviously a compound adjective.

Answer (score 1):

It makes perfect sense.

*worry free* is a phrase that has [increasing usage in the last couple of decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=worry+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworry%20free%3B%2Cc0) .

I might have typed it "worry-free", but that'd be a matter of taste.

Perhaps it appeals to our sense of "making sense" because it is so similar to the actual word "carefree".   As far as I know, worryfree is not a word, though.

Comment: I'm not sure the hyphenation is a matter of taste. *Fowler* says that compound attributive adjectives should be hyphenated unless the first part is an adverb ending in *-ly*.

Comment: Nice one - I didn't know that!

Comment: @chiastic-security Hyphenation is a matter of punctuation, which is a matter of style.  Pick your manual of style.  Fowler says compound attributive adjectives should be hyphenated unless the first part is an adverb ending in *-ly*?  And we should listen to Fowler, why?  The *Chicago Manual of Style* recommends four exceptions to that rule.  Why shouldn't we listen to *CMS* instead?  Many of Fowler's "rules" merely enshrined his prejudices.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it makes sense (grammatically correct, too) and doesn't have difficulty in getting the message across, I would hesitate to use *live a worry-free life* as it doesn't sound as idiomatic as *live a happy life*.

I would suggest using *live free from worry* as it is more idiomatic and the linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+free+from+worry%2C+live+a+worry+free+life&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20free%20from%20worry%3B%2Cc0) doesn't show any usage of *live a worry-free (worry free) life*.

As JEL commented above, it would be even better and more idiomatic to say *I want to live without worry*. [[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+without+worry%2C+live+free+from+worry&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20without%20worry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20free%20from%20worry%3B%2Cc0)]